# Server templating versus Javascript client-side templating

Tags: django, templates, client-side, mustache, handlebars.js

I have recently been studying different options ([iCanHaz.js + Mustache.js](http://icanhazjs.com/), [jQuery templating](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), [Handlebars.js + Mustache.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) to generate the content from the client side. But I am not really sure this is good for SEO.

I am using Django on the Backend

I clearly see the advantages of processing / rendering less HTML on the server BUT, is this solution good for SEO?

Does crawlers read AJAX / Javascript generated HTML?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/distal/wiki/FAQ#Do_you_support_search_engine_optimization?

Answer (score -1):

Google crawler read specially marked js|ajax content. But is fact - ajax for seo is bad. JS templating like knockout only for dynamic forms or wizards imho.